# PHP - Check for leading 0's in 2 comma-delimited integers

Tags: php, regex

I have a user-input string with 2 comma-delimited integers.

**Example (OK):**

```
3,5
```

I want to reject any user input that contains leading 0's for either number.

**Examples (Bad):**

```
03,5
00005,3
05,003
```

Now what I *could* do is separate the two numbers into 2 separate `string`'s and use `ltrim` on each one, then see if they have changed from before `ltrim` was executed:

```
$string = "03,5";

$string_arr = explode(",",$string);

$string_orig1 = $string_arr[0];
$string_orig2 = $string_arr[1];

$string_mod1 = ltrim($string_orig1, '0');
$string_mod2 = ltrim($string_orig2, '0');

if (($string_mod1 !== $string_orig1) || ($string_mod2 !== $string_orig2)){
    // One of them had leading zeros!
}
```

..but this seems unnecessarily verbose. Is there a cleaner way to do this? Perhaps with `preg_match`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the current answers fail if any of the values are simply `0`.

You can just convert to integer and back and compare the result.

```
$arr = explode(',', $input);
foreach($arr as $item) {
    if( (str)intval($item) !== $item ) {
        oh_noes();
    }
}
```

However I am more curious as to why this check matters at all.

Comment: Won't work if the string is `3.5,5` since it will int cast `3.5`

Comment: Nevermind: *I have a user-input string with 2 comma-delimited **integers***

Comment: Users are passing in a `LIMIT` value for a `SQL SELECT LIMIT` query with a `limit` parameter in their URL (ex. `&limit=0,3`). I decided to make the user correct any leading 0's instead of trimming them off myself when making the `SQL` query.

Comment: `limit 0,05` is just as valid as `limit 0,5`

Comment: You should also rely as little upon user formatting as possible, eg: have separate `limit` and `offset` fields. You also need to be as strict as is possible when validating this input as it's not possible to parameterize the `LIMIT` statement and this is a potential venue for SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

You could shorten the code and check if the first character of each part is a zero:

```
$string = "03,5";
$string_arr = explode(",",$string);
if ($string_arr[0][0] === "0" || $string_arr[1][0] === "0") {
    echo "not valid";
} else {
    echo "valid";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using `preg_match`.  We can try matching for the pattern:

```
\b0\d+
```

The `\b` would match either the start of the string, *or* a preceding comma separator.

If we find such a match, it means that we found one or more numbers in the CSV list (or a single number, if only one number present) which had a leading zero.

```
$input = "00005,3";
if (preg_match("/\b0\d+/", $input)) {
    echo "no match";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple check that if the first character is `0` (using `[0]`) or that `,0` exists in the string

```
if ( $string[0] == "0" || strpos($string, ",0") !== false ) {
    // One of them had leading zeros!
}
```

Comment: This is as far as I can see the best method. I can't vision a way that would be easier or lighter.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be with `/^([1-9]+),(\d+)/`; a regex that checks the string starts with one or more non-zero digits, followed by a comma, then one or more digits.

`preg_match('/^([1-9]+),(\d+)/', $input_line, $output_array);`

This separates the digits into two groups and explicitly avoids leading zeros.

This can be seen on Regex101 **[here](https://regex101.com/r/pdyL85/2/)** and PHPLiveRegex **[here](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/qFo)**.